# get Response asyncTask and throw new Intent android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How can i get the response of a asyncTask and change my UI?

```
 public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response> {

        @Override
        protected Response doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Response response = get(params[0], params[1]);
                responseString = response.body().string();
                return response;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private Response get(String url, String base) throws IOException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(url)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base)
                    .build();
            return client.newCall(request).execute();
        }
    }
```

This is my loginTask that connect with my restful service. The webservice return a boolean with the result. If the user exist return true, if not return false.

Here i received the boolean correctly:

```
Response response = get(params[0], params[1]);
                    responseString = response.body().string();
                    return response;
```

But i cant check if responseString is equals as false or true and it is true change my activity.

How can i do that?

Comment: once you return from doInbackground method of AsyncTask, onPostExecute method is called,which runs on Main thread, so you can update the UI there

Comment: i do that but i am not sure if it is correct:

if (responseString.equals("true")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistroActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en el logueo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

because i use getApplicattionConext() inside MainActivity Context.

Comment: yes ofcourse you can use application context, what you are doing is correct.

Comment: thanks. you help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter (Response) here: AsyncTask is the type of the response that you are getting. If your service return true or false as boolean it should be

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
```

Besides doInBackground, you can to override and onPostExecute

```
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) 
   {
       if(result)
       {
           //is true
       }
       else
       {
           //is false
       }
   }
```